# How to convert timestamp into date in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Can someone please tell me that how to convert timestamp into date in neo4j.
Suppose I have a long field to store millis.

Now i want to convert it into date through cypher.

**NOTE**- it would be great if it's possible without using apoc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes surely you can do it

```
return date(datetime({epochmillis:timestamp()}))
```

[more readings](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/temporal/)